# Is it possible to get rid of the input field with react-select?

Tags: reactjs

I'm using [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-select) package with React, and Im trying to use it as a "result dropdown" for a search. The problem is that I can't seem to get rid of the input field. There is a prop called `isSearchable`, however all it does is disable the input, it doesn't hide it. My fall back is to either fork it or use another package, but I would really like to get this one working.

I'm currently using it as,

```
const options = [
  { value: "chocolate", label: "Chocolate" },
  { value: "strawberry", label: "Strawberry" },
  { value: "vanilla", label: "Vanilla" }
];

<Select
  hideSelectedOptions
  menuIsOpen={true}
  isSearchable={false}
  options={options}
>
```

But this just renders:
[image: img]

Is it possible to get rid of the input, where it says "Select..."? There's also very little difference with the `isDisabled` prop, it seems a bit redundant.

Answer (score 3):

Figured it out.

```
<Select
  components={{
    Control: () => null
  }}
  options={options}
/>
```